# Unknown error in script using awk

Tags: linux, bash, file, charts, scripting

The title might seem a bit unclear.

This is my first script:

```
#!/bin/bash

read $1
tijd=$(($minuten*60))
echo "Het script zal elke" '$1' "minuten de tijd naar buiten printen "
echo "De resultaten worden in het bestand ''Grafiek.txt'' geplaatst, activeer ''script2.sh'' om de grafiek te creeren. "

while true; do

    Datum=$(date "+%x %H:%M")
    Snelheid=$(speedtest |grep -oP '^Download: \K.*')

    sleep $tijd

    echo "$Datum $Snelheid" >> Grafiek.txt

done
```

This is how the content of the file Grafiek looks :

```
21/12/16 18:50 355.44 Mbits/s 
21/12/16 18:52 161.59 Mbits/s 
21/12/16 18:54 101.52 Mbits/s
```

This is my second script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for fn in `cat Grafiek.txt`; do

DatumDag="$(awk 'BEGIN{FS=" "}{print $1}' Grafiek.txt)"
DatumUur="$(awk 'BEGIN{FS=" "}{print $2}' Grafiek.txt)"
Snelheid="$(awk 'BEGIN{FS=" "}{print $3}' Grafiek.txt)"

IntSnelheid=${Snelheid%[.]*}
Aantalsterretjes=$(($IntSnelheid/20))
Grafiek=" "

for ((i=0; i<$Aantalsterretjes+1; i++))
    do
    Grafiek="$Grafiek*"
done

echo "DatumDag DatumUur Grafiek"
done
```

The first script works perfectly. I just wanted to get the download speed and print out the "chart" which is named "grafiek

this is how the echo of script2 should look:

```
 21/12/16 18:50 355.44 Mbits/s *******
 21/12/16 18:52 161.59 Mbits/s ****
 21/12/16 18:54 101.52 Mbits/s **
```

Script2 has multiple errors and i can't put my hands on it.

I think the main error is can't do anything arithmetic with the "Snelheid" it means speed.

Can anybody figure out what's wrong?

Comment: You aren't using the value of `$fn` anywhere. It looks like you want to use that, not the contents of `Project2.txt`, to set the value of those 3 variables.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like the following for your second script. The only thing I've really changed is that you parse a line from `Grafiek.txt`, not the contents of `Project2.txt`, to set the variables `DatumDag`, `DatumUur`, and `Snelheid`. (See [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for the reason I replaced your `for` loop with a `while` loop.)

```
while read -r DatumDag DatumUur Snelheid units; do

  IntSnelheid=${Snelheid%.*}
  Aantalsterretjes=$(($IntSnelheid/20))

  Grafiek=" "
  for ((i=0; i<$Aantalsterretjes+1; i++)); do
    Grafiek="$Grafiek*"
  done

  echo "$DatumDag $DatumUur $Snelheid $units $Grafiek"

done < Grafiek.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r line; do
    speed=${line%.*}
    speed=${speed##* }
    speed=$(printf %$((speed/20))s)
    echo "$line ${speed// /*}"
done < Grafiek.txt
```

running...

```
$ ./a.sh                                               
21/12/16 18:50 355.44 Mbits/s *****************
21/12/16 18:52 161.59 Mbits/s ********
21/12/16 18:54 101.52 Mbits/s *****
```